# WebSocket server support

Tags: http, html, websocket

I'm new to WebSocket and HTML5. Before today, I thought that all the HTML5 standards affect only the clients(broswers); so assume that users have upgraded their broswers, its ready. But after some reading on WebSocket, it seems to me that I need to install something on the server to support it. Am I understand it right?

As an example, if I have a website on a shared hosting like Hostmonster, which I don't have the privilege to change the http server, can I use WebSocket?

Btw, by server I don't mean "proxy" server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets are work in progress, and not part of HTML5 at all. The API is being defined by the W3C WebApps WG, the protocol in the IETF HyBI WG.

And yes: browsers at some time will ship with support for it (everything currently shipping is experimental and already already out of date), but servers will need special support as well.

Comment: It may not officially be part of HTML5 standard any longer, but everybody considers it part of HTML5. There are a bunch of interesting things that aren't technically part of the HTML5 standard itself that everybody considers part of HTML5 (the general concept): web workers, microdata, device element, web storage, etc: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_various_versions_of_the_spec.3F  Even the w3 version is located under html5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Comment: kanaka - just because people are sloppy with the term doesn't make it correct.